# Declaring a generic variable in a type in F#

Tags: .net, f#

How do I declare that I want something of type `'a` which I have no value for yet.

```
type MyType<'a> =
    let mutable something:'a = ??
    let setSomething item:'a =
        something <- a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Unchecked.defaultof<'a>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353732.aspx). That said, a nicer way for me would be to make `something` an Option of 'a. That way the intention of ”not having a value“ would be made clearer.

```
type MyType<'a> =
    let mutable something:'a option = None
    let setSomething (item:'a) =
        something <- Some a
```

Comment: Cool! Does `option` also apply if the MyType is supposed to be used with other .NET languages?

Comment: Yes, it's a regular .NET type (you'll need to reference F# libraries though).